# Converting xsd to c# with xsd.exe - getting errors with extended ascii characters

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I am using the Microsoft command line tool xsd.exe to convert a xsd file to c# classes.
I am encountering a error everytime the xsd file encounters a extended ascii character.

For example this word Côte causes a error.  Specifically this character causes the error:  ô

Is there a way to force the xsd app to accept these?  I really do not want to edit every single one.

Comment: What text encoding are the xsd files in?

Comment: I'm affraid, not.

Comment: Everything else is regular ascii....except like four places where it uses these : ô.